# How to reference all tables in a Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to execute VBA code on multiple tables in Word.

I tried referencing/adding numbers to add more tables to execute the script on at the `ActiveDocument.Tables(1)` line.

I don't know how to reference all tables 1 through 4.

I am left to duplicate the macro below and enter "(2)", "(3)", "(4)" for the `ActiveDocument.Tables` number to reach all of the tables.

```vb
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    For r = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        fnd = False
        For Each c In .Rows(r).Cells
            If InStr(c.Range.Text, "ARORA") > 0 Then fnd = True
        Next
        For Each c In .Rows(r).Cells
            If InStr(c.Range.Text, "Description of Change") > 0 Then fnd = True
        Next
        If Not fnd Then .Rows(r).Delete
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

The code removes rows from the specified table which contain the specified text "c.Range.Text". This executes only for the one table specified at ActiveDocument.Tables (i.e., "(1)", etc.).

I need this to run for all 4 tables, 1, 2, 3, and 4 in my Word document.

Comment: Why not use For Each t in ActiveDocument.Tables, analogous to what's being done for Cells?

Comment: Has the problem been solved for you, Lance?

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each Table In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For r = Table.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        fnd = False
        For Each c In Table.Rows(r).Cells
            If InStr(c.Range.Text, "PartnerAbbr") > 0 Then fnd = True
        Next
        For Each c In Table.Rows(r).Cells
            If InStr(c.Range.Text, "Description of Change") > 0 Then fnd = True
        Next
```

Comment: I found how to reference all of the tables and the rows within the tables for the active document, seen above (although thank you for the recommendation, Cindy!)

Comment: You can mark this as the solution using the little green checkmark on the left. This will earn you points.